# Find a generator polynomial and generator matrix of a triple error-correcting [15, 5] binary cyclic code

Tags: encoding, coding-style

Find a generator polynomial and generator matrix of a triple error-correcting [15, 5] binary cyclic code.

Here q=2,n=15andk=5. So,|T|=15−5=10.
2-cyclotomic cosets: C0 = {0},C1 = {1,2,4,8},C3 = {3,6,12,9},C5 = {5,10} and C7 = {7, 14, 13, 11}.
Since |T | = 10, we need to choose two cyclotomic cosets of size 4 and one cyclotomic cosets of size 2.
As C is triple error correcting code, d ≥ 2 · 3 + 1 = 7. That implies, T needs to contain δ − 1 ≥ 6 consecutive integers.
Then T =C1 ∪C3 ∪C5 ={1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12}.
Let α be a primitive element of IF2t where t = ord15(2) = 4.
Consider the primitive binary polynomial x4 + x + 1 of degree 4, i.e., α4 + α + 1 = 0.
Then the generator polynomial g(x) = Qi∈T (x − αi). Using α15 = 1 and α4 = α + 1,
we have, M 0 ( x ) = ( x + α 0 ) = x + 1 ∈ IF 2 [ x ] ;
M1(x) = (x+α1)(x+α2)(x+α4)(x+α8) = (x+α)(x+α2)(x+α+1)(x+α2 +1) = x4+x3+x2+x+1 ∈ IF2[x]; M3(x) = (x+α3)(x+α6)(x+α12)(x+α9) = (x+α3)(x+α3+α2)(x+ α3+α2+α+1)(x+α3+α) = x4+x3+1 ∈ IF2[x];
M5(x) = (x+α5)(x+α10) = x2+x+1 ∈ IF2[x];
M7(x) = (x+α7)(x+α14)(x+α13)(x+α11) = (x+α3)(x+α3 +α2)(x+α3 +α2 +α+ 1)(x+α3 +α)=x4 +x+1∈IF2[x].
Hence, the generator matrix of C is g(x) = M1(x)M3(x)M5(x) = (x4 + x3 + x2 + x + 1)(x2 + x+1)(x2 +x+1).
Generator matrix ?

Is this correct if not then give correct answer